# Can't install ubuntu-touch (dual boot) on mobile (stuck in <waiting for device>)

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android

Here is the output after running `./dualboot.sh` ([link here](http://humpolec.ubuntu.com/latest/dualboot.sh))

```
No device ID specified, picking first available device
Waiting for device CB006626 to install Ubuntu installer to.
Detected connected Aquaris-5
Downloading recovery for aquaris5
ls: cannot access recovery-aquaris5-6.0.4.3.img: No such file or directory
Skipping download, file already downloaded
Dev:CB006626: selected full install
Downloading SU package
Skipping download, file already downloaded
Downloading Ubuntu Installer application package
Skipping download, file already downloaded
install_ubuntu_installer<<
Dev:CB006626: Rebooting to bootloader
Waiting for device to be connected in normal or recovery mode
recovery-aquaris5-6.0.4.3.img        #I echoed the path to unbunt_installer
CB006626                             #I echoed the device_id
< waiting for device >
```

And my device stays [like this](http://forums.androidcentral.com/attachments/lg-g3/160785d1422313188t-how-do-i-get-my-phone-out-fastboot-mode-started-image.jpg) reading `=> FASTBOOT mode...`

Also, my device is an Aquarius e5 full-hd. It wasn't recognized by the bash file because it was looking for aquarius5 so it said "not supported" but it must be supported because it is an aq5 after all, just full-hd. This is, I changed

```
elif [[ "$DEVICE" == bq_Aquaris5* ]]; then
    echo "Detected connected Aquaris-5"
    DEVICE=$AQUARIS5
```

to:

```
elif [[ "$DEVICE" == Aquaris_E5* ]]; then
    echo "Detected connected Aquaris-5"
    DEVICE=$AQUARIS5
```

Any idea on why? What could be the problem? Tyvm for your feedback

Comment: Well this sounds like fastboot doesn't work properly. Can you boot to boot loader and do fastboot -devices?

Comment: @Marton how could I check this? The bootloader identifies the device but I had to install it indeed. Before, running dualboot.sh would error with `no fastboot command present, insall` or something similar...

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong about fastboot.  So  have you currently installed Android? If yes I'd ask you to enable "USB-Debugging" in developer options. Then connect your device to your pc and start the script.

Comment: @Marton Can you post that as an answer? The problem seems to be on the line `adb -s $DEVICE_ID reboot bootloader`; I tested the command used by the script to initialize `$DEVICE_ID` (`adb devices | grep -w 'device' | awk '{ print $1}'`) and it works perfectly as long as USB debugging is enabled on the device and as long as the user has allowed the connection on the device by tapping OK on the popup, so I'd say that 99% the problem is that OP doesn't have USB debugging enabled.

Comment: @Fane Could you please rewrite your first comment, because I don't understand it?

Comment: @Fane - is mobile bricked somehow ?! You would then need a dead spot for to flash it with flashtool. Those W-Lan devices can only be flashed in dead spots  (when they are bricked).

Answer (score 1):

I was trying exactly the same, same setup, and I think the critical error is this:

```
Downloading recovery for aquaris5
ls: cannot access recovery-aquaris5-6.0.4.3.img: No such file or directory
```

or as I had it:

```
Waiting for device to be connected in normal or recovery mode
Dev:: Waiting for fastboot to be ready
cannot load 'recovery-aquaris5-6.0.4.3.img': No such file or directory
Dev:: Waiting for adb recovery to be ready
```

The problem is that the script uses:

```
# Used version of CWM recovery
URL_CWM_PATH_BASE="http://download2.clockworkmod.com/recoveries/recovery-clockwork"
```

... but if you go to http://download2.clockworkmod.com/recoveries/recovery-clockwork:

```
    This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
  <Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message>...</Error>
```

... so, clearly, the recovery images cannot be downloaded from here any more... There seems to be another website now:

- https://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager

... but there are no Aquaris ROMs there...

---

EDIT: Ok, did a bit more looking up into this. First, probably the title of this question should include "dual boot", because the `dualboot.sh` script is from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/DualBootInstallation.

Anyways, this is the thing: this script and concept (as on the Wiki page) assume there is stock Android on this device, and have relied on ClockworkMod (CWM) custom recovery image; it seems there was such an image for an Aquaris E5 in the past, but not anymore. Right now, the only custom recovery image which supports Aquaris E5 seems to be TWRP (Team Win Recovery Project), see:

- https://twrp.me/Devices/
- https://dl.twrp.me/vegetahd/twrp-3.0.2-0-vegetahd.img.html

I flashed my phone with this recovery image as per http://www.mibqyyo.com/comunidad/discussion/77467/how-to-root-a-bq-aquaris-e5-hd-phone ; and I was wondering if the dual boot could be used with this recovery instead.

First, the `dualboot.sh` basically does a sideload of `UPDATE-SuperSU-v1.93.zip` and [`UPDATE-UbuntuInstaller.zip`](http://humpolec.ubuntu.com/UPDATE-UbuntuInstaller.zip); here the SuperSU application will already be there from the TWRP recovery rooting procedure, and then we're left with `UPDATE-UbuntuInstaller.zip`. This zip can actually be sideloaded from a PC using the TWRP recovery, and then we get a "Ubuntu Dual Boot" app when Android is booted. Unfortunately,

> It appears the device is not supported... Aquaris_E5_HD

Note that this device may appear as:

```
$ adb devices -l
List of devices attached
UA00XXXX               recovery usb:1-1.3 product:omni_vegetahd model:Aquaris_E5_HD device:vegetahd
# or
UA00XXXX               sideload usb:1-1.3
# or
UA00XXXX               device usb:1-1.3 product:Aquaris_E5_HD model:Aquaris_E5_HD device:Aquaris_E5_HD
```

Here, we can get the source of this app:

```
$ bzr branch lp:humpolec
$ cd humpolec/
```

... and then, in (`humpolec/`)`src/com/canonical/ubuntu/installer/Utils.java`, do this hack:

```
public static boolean isBringupMode() {
    if (!UbuntuInstallService.BRINGUP_MODE) {
        String deviceModel = Build.DEVICE.toLowerCase(Locale.US);
        if ("bq_aquaris5".equals(deviceModel)) {
            return true;
        }
        if ("aquaris_e5_hd".equals(deviceModel)) { // ADD..
            return true;                           // ..
        }                                          // ..THIS
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

... and then to build:

```
JAVA_HOME=/path/to/android/jdk1.6.0_45 \
PATH=${PATH}:/path/to/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140321/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030/bin:/path/to/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140321/sdk/tools:/path/to/android/jdk1.6.0_45/bin  \
ANDROID_HOME=/path/to/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140321/sdk \
ant debug
```

Here, to be able to sideload, you'll have to first unpack the `UPDATE-UbuntuInstaller.zip` as a directory, say, `UPD-Ub`, and then replace the `.apk` in there with the one built in previous step, and then repack the zip:

```
cp -a UPD-Ub UPD-UbNew
cp -a humpolec/bin/UbuntuInstaller-debug.apk UPD-UbNew/system/app/UbuntuInstaller.apk
rm -rf UPD-UbNew/system/app/UbuntuInstaller_apk # from previous unzip
(cd UPD-UbNew; zip -r ../UPDATE-UbuntuInstallerNew.zip .)
```

Then, when booted in TWRP recovery, you can sideload from PC with:

```
adb sideload UPDATE-UbuntuInstallerNew.zip
```

... and the updated app will install on phone.

Here, the app will open, and will even download from a channel (I tried `stable/bq-aquaris.en`) and unpack - however when you finally do "Reboot to Ubuntu" in the app, it will simply reboot to TWRP recovery. The problem is, the app still expects CWM recovery, and basically copies the data it downloaded in directories specific to CWM, not TWRP. And since CWM does not have a ROM for this device anymore, the app as such is unfortunately unusable for dual boot on this device.

The only other option for dual boot on Aquaris E5 seems to be MultiROM Manager app for Android, which seems to be based on/work with TWRP recovery - unfortunately, it does not recognize this device either: when it is started, it states: "This is unsupported device (Aquaris_E5_HD)!"

Answer (score 0):

Just enable USB-Debugging in your Android developer options and click "OK" when a popup appears.

For explanation: Without USB-Debugging your computer can't send commands to your phone.