# ubuntu-device-flash can't find BQ Aquaris 4.5

Tags: boot, ubuntu-touch, phone

I tried to reinstall Ubutnu Touch on my BQ Aquaris 4.5. But the precess got stuck somewhere. So i tried to do it again, but i can't reach the device anymore. If it is in boot mode and i do "ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en --bootstrap" i only get "Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting " . Nothing more ever happens than.

The device does not boot normal anymore. It gets stuck on the screen with the bq logo.

What can I do now ?

Comment: similar question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/666070/cant-install-ubuntu-touch-on-mobile-stuck-in-waiting-for-device

Comment: How can i find the $DEVICE_ID  ? and where can i enable USB debuggin ?

Answer (score 0):

1. unplug device
2. plug device in
3. `dmesg`
4. you will see info about manufacturer and device_id in the last few lines

To enter the bootloader hold `power` and `volume +` buttons untill the light under speaker flashes then release `power` and choose `[Fastboot Mode]` in the menu then you will be able to install OS